# $x^2+(a-3)x-4a-4=0$ Find square roots for the equation with a parameter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, problem-solving

> Solve the following equation for $x$: $$x^2+(a-3)x-4a-4=0$$

The book I am reading says that the roots are: $x_1=4, x_2 = -a-1$.

I am stuck in showing that these are the roots.

My notes:
$$D=a^2+10a+25$$
And I can use any $a$ for $D$, because there is no opportunity for $D<0$

Comment: $D=(a+5)^2\ge0$, apply the formula can find the roots

Comment: @Tim , Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^{2}+(a-3)x-4a-4=0$$

Using Bashkara's formula:
$$x=\frac{-b±\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}$$

We have:

$$x=\frac{(-a+3)±\sqrt{(a-3)^{2}-4×(-4a-4)}}{2}$$
$$x = \frac{-a+3±\sqrt{a^{2}-6a+9+16a+16}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{-a+3±\sqrt{a^{2}+10a+25}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{-a+3±\sqrt{(a+5)^{2}}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{-a+3±(a+5)}{2}$$

So we have that

$$x=\frac{-a+3+a+5}{2}$$ or $$x=\frac{-a+3-a-5}{2}$$

So we have that $x=4$ or $x=-a-1$.

Comment: Why have I got a -1 point to my question?

Comment: David, you should learn to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: "\frac{}{}" would be good

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will take it into account.

Answer (score 2):

Completing square no $D$:
$$x^2+(a-3)x-4a-4=0$$
$$\tiny x^2+
(a-3)x+\left(\frac{a-3}{2}\right)^2-4a-4=\left(\frac{a-3}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\tiny\left(x+\frac{a-3}{2}\right)^2=4a+4+\frac{a^2-6a+9}{4}$$
$$\small\left(x+\frac{a-3}{2}\right)^2=\frac{a^2+10a+25}{4}$$
$$\left(x+\frac{a-3}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{a+5}{2}\right)^2$$
$$\left|x+\frac{a-3}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{a+5}{2}\right|$$
$$x+\frac{a-3}{2}=\pm\frac{a+5}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{-a+3\pm(a+5)}{2}$$
$$x_1=\frac{-a+3+a+5}{2}=4$$
$$\small x_2=\frac{-a+3-a-5}{2}=-a-1$$

Comment: I am adjusting the solution according to screen of my mobile phone. That is why I used tiny and small fonts.

Comment: Original Poster is angry.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, OP doesn't have right to upvote/downvote cause their low reputation.

Comment: Hmmm... My colleague did then.

Comment: Thank you my office mate! I dont like reputstion and fame. Dangerous.

Comment: Both answers to this question have -1. It was not me :o

Comment: I can't vote, if you really care. Is this kind of solutions common? Maybe you have some algorithms or you just came up with the idea by yourself?

Comment: It is a very standard method to solve quadratic equations. So is downvoting:) But to do the same for cubic equation is very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $x^2+(a-3)x-4a-4=0$ can be factored:

$$x^2+(a-3)x-4(a+1)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (x-4)(x+(a+1))=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x-4=0~{\rm or~}x+(a+1)=0,$$ hence $$x\in \{4,-a-1\}.$$